# Cannot use my private mail due to Gmail as "Mail Setting" in Advanced DNS settings

Tags: dns, google-search-console, namecheap

I want to use Google Webmaster tool for my website. And, I also want to use the private email id for my domain name.

**Problem:** For G-Suite verification, I had to choose "Gmail" in the **Mail Settings** but due to this, my Private Domain Email id has stopped working.

[image]

I spoke to NameCheap customer service and they told me that I cannot use both Gmail and Private mail simultaneously.

[image]

**Question:** I had to chose "Gmail" as my mail setting just to verify my domain by TXT Records. Can I now set my Mail Setting back to "Private Mail" since my domain is already verified? ***Although I put TXT Record in Advanced DNS setting, but my domain did not get verified until I set Mail Settings to Gmail*** so, I am afraid that my account will become unverified if Google tries to do reverification.

Comment: Not sure why you have tagged this question with Google Analytics, I can't see any reference to GA in the text of the question.

Comment: Maybe it should go on another site. Webmasters or superuser? I'm not sure but I think it's off topic for stack overflow.

Comment: @Wes: There many other questions in Stackoverflow with the same tags. The question is related to google-webmaster verification process and since the tag exists in Stack overflow then, I don't know how this question is irrelevant to SO.